# Spring - SessionAttribute problem

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to implement something like this:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("promotion")
class PromotionController {
    @RequestMapping("showPromo")
    void showPromotionInfo(
        @RequestParam("promId") String promotionId,
        @ModelAttribute Promotion promotion, Errors errors
    ) {
        promotion = Promotions.get(promotionId);
        if (promotion == null || promotion.validates() == false) {
            errors.reject("promotion.invalid");
        }
        return "prom";
    }    
}
```

The code is invalid, wont work and has some bad errors, but I don't know how to write it better.

When user comes to an URL "showPromo?promId=15", controller should validate if the promotion is valid (outdated/non-existent/etc.). If it is valid - it should show it's information and save the promotion to model and session. If it's not - it should show some error about promotion being invalid.

Problem is, I need to save the promotion in the session (for several requests) and don't want to use direct session management. Is it currently possible with Spring? Or am I doing something wrong?

Could you please provide the optimal solution to my problem using Spring 3?

Thanks in advance.

Added:

Ok, I think I'll write down the problematic points:

1. When there is no object in session, it can't be bound with @ModelAttribute throwing an error like "no object found in session". And there is no "optional" parameter anywhere.
2. I can't have @ModelAttribute in the parameters, as I'm overwriting that promotion object. Proper way should be model.addAttribute("promotion", promotion). But I also need to have a way to provide errors, and I see no way to provide them using model.addAttribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to skaffman's answer: you can associate `BindingResult`s with manually added model attributes using `BindingResult.MODEL_KEY_PREFIX`.

```
Promotion promotion = .... 
modelMap.addAttribute("promotion", promotion); 
if (!promotion.validate()) {
    BindingResult errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(promotion, "promotion");
    errors.reject("promotion.invalid");
    model.put(BindingResult.MODEL_KEY_PREFIX + "promotion", errors);
}
```

Note, however, that you can't associate `BindingResult` with `null` object, therefore you can't use `errors.reject` when promotion was not found (if you don't add some kind of empty promotion into model in that case).

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was exactly what I wanted to know. However, this code looks pretty depressing (I mean the string-based attribute name)... Could there be some better (prettier) way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

promotion = Promotions.get(promotionId);

Above is your line of code.  Promotion(s).get(promotionId);  // exclude that "s" I placed in ()... 
That SHOULD help you in one case.

Another thing that COULD help you is when you do your @ModelAttribute("bindingVariable").  You should place one in there which in your case would bind to Promotion promotion,

If you have a CHECK block there....  You should have a view to go to IF it fails (should be handled some how)...  AND if it succeeds.  You have no handling on this as far as I can see.